# Colour of image is being changed after conversion from PIL image to numpy array and converting it back

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

Here is my code

```
    img = Image.open('./data/imgs/' + '0.jpg')
    //converting to numpy array
    img.load()
    imgdata = np.asarray(img)
    np.interp(imgdata, (imgdata.min(), imgdata.max()), (0, +1))
    //converting back to PIL image
    image = imgdata * 255
    image = Image.fromarray(image.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
    image.show()
```

**Here is my output with color distortion**
[image]

How to solve this?

Comment: Please show your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason for the problem:**
You are not using the return value of np.interp, so the the imgdata is not replaced by the new values. Thus it retains the initial range of values as [0, 255] and its dtype also is np.uint8. When you did imgdata * 255 it could not fit the results in np.uint8 and it overflowed(but starting from 0 again as it's unsigned).
**Assumption:**
I assume that you wanted to map the image values from [min(), max()] to [0, 1] and then rescale it back by multiplying it with 255.
**Solution:**
If my assumption about your code is true, do this:

```
imgdata = np.interp(imgdata, (imgdata.min(), imgdata.max()), (0, +1))
```

else remove (* 255) from the code and change it to,

```
image = imgdata
```

You can test this overflow by taking a sample array as follows:

```
sample = np.array([10, 20, 30], dtype=np.uint8)
sample2 = sample * 10
print(sample, sample2)
```

you will see that values of sample2 are [100, 200, 44] but not [100, 200, 300]

Comment: yes absolutely. I would keep im mind that np.interp in not in place. thanks again

Comment: Then can you please accept this as answer. Check this out if you don't know how, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work